# Kubernetes ServiceAccount cannot list some resources (K8s 1.24)

Tags: kubernetes, service-accounts, rbac

My service account cannot list some resources even though the Role and Rolebinding have enough privileges.

I see this error

```
2023-09-08T15:30:21.875Z    INFO    controller  k8s.io/client-go@v0.26.6/tools/cache/reflector.go:169: 
failed to list *v1.Lease: leases.coordination.k8s.io is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:karpenter:karpenter" 
cannot list resource "leases" in API group "coordination.k8s.io" 
in the namespace "kube-node-lease"
```

When I check the service account auth, I see the following error.

```
➜  ~ kubectl auth  can-i get leases --as system:serviceaccount:karpenter:karpenter
error: You must be logged in to the server (the server has asked for the client to provide credentials (post selfsubjectaccessreviews.authorization.k8s.io))
```

Role/Rolebinding

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: karpenter-lease
  namespace: kube-node-lease
  labels:
    helm.sh/chart: karpenter-v0.30.0
    app.kubernetes.io/name: karpenter
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: karpenter
    app.kubernetes.io/version: "0.30.0"
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: Role
  name: karpenter-lease
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: karpenter
    namespace: karpenter
---
# Source: karpenter/templates/role.yaml
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
  name: karpenter-lease
  namespace: kube-node-lease
  labels:
    helm.sh/chart: karpenter-v0.30.0
    app.kubernetes.io/name: karpenter
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: karpenter
    app.kubernetes.io/version: "0.30.0"
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
rules:
  # Read
  - apiGroups: ["coordination.k8s.io"]
    resources: ["leases"]
    verbs: ["get", "list", "watch"]
  # Write
  - apiGroups: ["coordination.k8s.io"]
    resources: ["leases"]
    verbs: ["delete"]
```

AFAR, K8s 1.24 had some breaking changes in Service Account Tokens, that's why, I also created a token for the service account, but it didn't seem to be working.

```
kubectl apply -f - <<EOF
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: karpenter
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/service-account.name: karpenter
type: kubernetes.io/service-account-token
EOF
```

Do you guys happen to face such an issue?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

To debug you should first make sure that the Secret and the serviceaccount objects are in the `Karpenter` namespace, because as per the yaml manifest of the secrets you provided, there is not namespace field.

One more thing, as per the command it looks not good, you must specify the namespace:

```
kubectl auth can-i get leases --as system:serviceaccount:karpenter:karpenter \ 
--namespace kube-node-lease
```

As per the second error `error: You must be logged in to the server (the server has asked for the client to provide credentials (post selfsubjectaccessreviews.authorization.k8s.io))`:

This is a quiet common and general error which is related to authentication problems against the API Server.

So make sure you are logged in to the correct context, to check you can run any other command to verify, for instance:

```
kubectl config current-context #to view your current context
kubectl get rolebinding,role, sa --namespace karpenter
```